# PowerShell If/Else

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am trying to write a script that will look at a folder, `%userprofile%\SCRATCH`, and provide the user with a pop up window if they have files in there that are more than two weeks old.

This is a script that will be run at logon. I am using `C:\Scratch` as a test, but I don't know how to use Windows variables in PowerShell.

```
$LogPath = "C:\SCRATCH" # Where to look for files
$Daysback = "-14" # Defines file age limit
$CurrentDate = Get-Date # Gets date created for current files.
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback) # Gets the date of the folder/files

Get-ChildItem $LogPath | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $DatetoDelete

If ($Datetodelete -gt 14)
{
    $a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
    $b = $a.popup(“Delete Test“,0,”Good Job!”,1)
}

else
{
    $a1 = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
    $b1 = $a.popup(“GTG Test“,0,”Good Job!”,1)
}
```

Something is wrong since I just get the "Delete Test" no matter what number I use in the `If` statement.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing curly brace on the end of the line that starts with `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: $env:USERPROFILE will give you windows user profile path (C:\Users\Travis, for example).

Comment: I had seen the $env:USERPROFILE on here before but what I"m not sure of is how to then append another folder to USERPROFILE.  I need to check the SCRATCH folder in the user's profile.

Comment: David,

Nice catch but i just failed at copying and pasting.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your intent in the if statement was to compare `$Datetodelete` with some date offset using the integer 14.  However, you are actually comparing to the integer 14, instead.

`$Datetodelete` is a `DateTime` object, so, if my assumption is correct, you need to compare it with another `DateTime` object in your if statement, instead of an integer.

Comment: Would the $DatetoDelete variable be another DateTime object?

Comment: That's what I said. `$Datetodelete`is a `DateTime` object. `$Datetodelete` is the result of an operation that you performed on `$CurrentDate`, which in turn was the result of calling `Get-Date`, which returns a `DateTime` object.  You can prove this to yourself by adding the line `Write-Output $Datetodelete.gettype().Name` to your code, immediately after the line where you assign `$Datetodelete`.